# Cannot delete dataframe column using mutating function

Tags: r

This function is supposed to delete the original dataframe's date column

```
nodates <- function(fr){
  fr <- dplyr::select(fr, -c(date))
}
```

But it doesn't work

```
fr = data.frame(k = c(1,2,3), date = c(2,3,4))
```

nodates(fr) doesn't change anything.

I've tried using the subset() function but that doesn't work either

Comment: You have to specify what is being returned at the end of the function. Typically, calling the object to return (here, `fr`) is enough.

Comment: you could remove `fr <- ` in the `nodates` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the changes are only visible in the function scope and not outside the function body like you want it to be when you call this function on a dataframe.

there are two options to modify the nodates function.

```
nodates <- function(fr) {
  fr <- dplyr::select(fr, -c(date))
  # explicitly return modified dataframe
  return(fr)
}

# or you can avoid assigning the dataframe like this
nodates <- function(fr) {
  fr %>% select(-date)
}
```